# Trigger Event Action when Back Button is Clicked in React

Tags: reactjs, back-button, browser-history

I have the following component

```
class NewCampaign extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.nextStep = this.nextStep.bind(this)
    this.previousStep = this.previousStep.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      page: 1,
    }
  }  

  nextStep() {
      var newStep = this.state.step +1;
       this.setState({ page: newStep })
  }

  previousStep() {  
      var newStep = this.state.step -1;
      this.setState({ page: newStep })
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <div className="campaign">
          {page === 1 && <Step1Page nextStep={this.nextStep}/>}
          {page === 2 && <Step2Page previousStep={this.previousStep} nextStep={this.nextStep}/>}
          {page === 5 && <Step5Page previousStep={this.previousStep} />}                              
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Currently, each Component Step page has 2 buttons: A prev and a next button, which, when clicked will update the state called page.

This works fine. However, now there is a request to enable the `Back Button` on the browser to go to the previous step.

I'm not sure if I can use `browser history` because I'm still on the same route. The only thing that is changing is the component state called `page` which is triggered by the two actions nextStep and PreviousStep.

Is there a way to find out when the back button is clicked and activate the `previousStep` action?